# Are the present infinitive of the active periphrastic and the future active infinitive of the verb the same concept?

Tags: verbs, participle, infinitive

On p270 of Keller's Learn to Read Latin

> The present infinitive of the active periphrastic is also used as the future active infinitive of the verb. Thus, for example, rectirus, -a, -um esse may be identified as the present infinitive of the active periphrastic of rego or the future active infinitive of rego.

Are the present infinitive of the active periphrastic and the future active infinitive of the verb the same concept?
Can one be used wherever the other is?

My understanding about the concept "periphrastic" is just a compound form of a word, if I am correct.

Are the present infinitive of the **passive** periphrastic is also used as the future **passive** infinitive of the verb?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Basically, yes. But that terminology is highly confusing, in my opinion.

In the terminology I'm used to, the periphrastic future goes like *recturus sum*, "I will rule". Its infinitival form is obviously *recturus esse*. It is only active, there is no passive.

The normal future is *regam*. Latin has no real future infinitive, so the infinitive from the periphrastic future is used, *recturus esse*.

This should be little surprise, because the periphrastic future is often used with the same meaning as the normal future; it can substituted for a normal future when a subjunctive is required, which the normal future does not have, or when there is some other reason why the normal future cannot be used, e.g. *Oedipus natus est Iocasta, quam postea nupturus erat*: "Oedipus was born to Jocasta, whom he would later wed". It is true that the participle *recturus* can have a specific shade of meaning, like *about to rule*; but in the periphrastic construction, as often as not, it has no specific meaning other than future.

The normal future can be made passive without problem, *regar*. But the periphrastic future cannot, because neither the future participle *recturus* nor the verb *esse* have passive forms. And this is very rarely 'needed' anyway: it would be very rare if it existed.

There is, however, some need for a passive future infinitive, because the normal future has no passive infinitive. So a special, passive kind of periphrastic future infinitive is normally used: *rectum iri*. Perhaps this *iri* may be from *eo* "go", which normally doesn't have any passive infinitive, but I don't know about that.

*Rectum* is the first supine: it does not agree with anything, it is always this form. So *dicit reginam necatum iri*: he says that the queen will be killed. *Regina dicitur necatum iri*: it is said that the queen will be killed.

*Regendus* is a gerundive. It is a passive verbal form, and it is somewhat like a participle in meaning, which is why I have occasionally heard it described as the future passive participle: but that is not its normal name, and its meaning is more specific than indicating mere future. It has strong modal connotations of obligation or weak possibility: "which must be ruled" or "which can be ruled", not "which will be ruled".

In some contexts, this difference in meaning is slight or zero, which is why you could possibly use *regendus esse* for a kind of passive future infinitive, sometimes. It would then of course be called periphrastic, because it is composed of two words 'circumscribing' and supplanting a form that doesn't actually exist (the future passive infinitive).

Comment: I also learned that *iri* comes from *eo, ire*. Given the existence of passive intransitive in Latin, is there a reason to doubt that derivation?

Comment: @cmw  Like cmw, I'm curious about the reason of your doubts (cf. above: "Perhaps this _iri_ may be from _eo_ "go", which normally doesn't have any passive infinitive, but I don't know about that"). It seems quite clear that _iri_ is an impersonal passive of the verb _eo_. In my opinion, what can be said to be debatable is its grammaticalization degree when used periphrastically (e.g. _necatum iri_) but not its existence.

Comment: @Cerberus As for "_regendus_ is a gerundive. It is a passive verbal form, and it is somewhat like a participle in meaning, which is why I have occasionally heard it described as the future passive participle", it's useful to remind these words from Pinkster's (2015) OLS: “The gerundive (...) was indeed described as a future passive participle by Latin grammarians but was not used as such before the third century AD" (p. 62); "interpretation of a gerundive as passive or (**more frequently) active** depends on contextual and sometimes on extralinguistic information" (p.295-bold mine: Mitomino).

Comment: @Mitomino: Oh, well, it's just that I don't remember ever reading about it, nor did I look it up, so I didn't want to assume. Who knows, it could have been from some archaic form of *esse*. But, yeah, passive forms of *eo* are common enough in impersonal usage. If both of you have learned that it is indeed from *eo*, then I have now learned this too.

Comment: @Mitomino: I didn't know Latin grammarians of the third century already described it as a participle. It's just not common in modern parlance, as far as I know. I'm not sure what he means by "active", though: if he is thinking of dominant gerundive constructions, surely those have a passive origin as well? The same applies to the impersonal gerundive (which I think you yourself analyse as a gerund btw.).

Comment: @Cerberus If you're interested in knowing more about the origin and disappearance of the passive future infinitive _iri_, you can take a look at this article (it is written in Spanish): click on "texto completo" and a pdf copy will show up: https://dialnet.unirioja.es/servlet/articulo?codigo=165899

Comment: @Cerberus The issue of when the gerundive has a passive or active meaning is quite complex. E.g. it has a clear passive meaning in _De provinciis ab iis qui obtinerent retinendis…_ (Cic. Fam. 12, 22, 1). I think Pinkster (2015: 294-295) is right when saying that it has an active meaning in exs. like _His enim ipsis legendis in memoriam redeo mortuorum_ (Cic. Sen. 21). There is debate when dealing with apparently simple examples like _Mater mihi laudanda est_. For many years, following the tradition, I thought the gerundive here is passive. Recently I've also changed my mind here.

Comment: @Mitomino: In Q: "https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/15229/1982, and the linked Q., we discussed the the gerundive, in the oblique cases, losing its deontic & passive qualities ("omittendis" & "inflammandam"). In this Pinkster ex., "legendis", is another such. I'm confused about the gerundive-of-obligation: "mater mihi laudanda est." = "Mother ought-to-be-praised by me.", why have you changed your mind on the passive nature, here?

Comment: @tony If you're interested in the complex issue of why the gerundive in this construction with the so-called "dative of agent" is not passive (despite the traditional analysis: cf. "the periphrastic passive"), I recommend you to take a look at this very descriptive (i.e. non-technical and hence, I think, quite readable) work, which is downloadable at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320958533_Between_the_Historical_Languages_and_the_Reconstructed_Language_An_Alternative_Approach_to_the_Gerundive_Dative_of_Agent_Construction_in_Indo-European

Comment: @Mitomino fascinating paper. The concept of oblique subjects and nominative objects will take me some time to internalize.

Comment: @Kingshorsey: I haven't read the paper, but that sounds like someone wanted to change the essential meanings of subject and object. As in some recent Anglo-Saxon schools of linguistics.

Comment: @Cerberus yeah the same author works in both fields. It’s definitely a different approach. And I’m not sure I like the terminology of oblique subjects. But there are some interesting cross-linguistic data being explained in a parsimonious way.

Answer (score 4):

The active (or first) periphrastic conjugation denotes a future or intended action. It competes with the normal future tense, which also denotes future actions, but generally does not have the connotation of present intention or immediacy (something being “about to happen”). [The distinction is often subtle.](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/15763/difference-between-future-participle-and-simple-future/15765#15765)

*Except* that the ordinary future tense lacks some things the other tenses have: It has no subjunctive, and, more importantly, no infinitive. So if you need a future infinitive, and it turns out you need that pretty often, then you use the infinitive of the active periphrastic instead.

Practical example: I'll go to Rome.

- **Me:** *Romam ibo.*
- **But I could also say:** *Romam iturus sum.* (But it has more the connotation of “I'm about to go to Rome, I intend to go to Rome.”)
- **Someone quoting me:** (has no other option than to say) *Sebastianus dixit Romam sese iturum esse.*

With this in mind, I think you will agree that “Can one be used wherever the other is?” is not answerable: There is only one, the other doesn't exist.